NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'verify-email' with keyword arguments '{}' not found 1 pattern(s) tried: ['verify_email/(?P<username>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']
This is an email verification code application for new user sign up
The user enters their username as email, and then email address, password and password confirmation. An otp code should be sent to the new user's email. The user must enter the otp code generated to verify the new user account sign up. There after the user can sign in.
I have entered all the form details into the form fields. The otp code gets sent to my email as expected but I am unable to enter the code generated due the following error message showing up after clicking sign up: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'verify-email' with keyword arguments '{'username': 'aikins.stefan@gmail.com'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['verify_email/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\Z']
Here is the code snippet:
urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [


path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("register", views.signup, name="register"),
path("verify_email/<slug:username>/", views.verify_email, name="verify-email"),
path("resend_otp", views.resend_otp, name="resend-otp"),
path("signin", views.signin, name="signin"),


]

models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.conf import settings




class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username"]

    def _str__(self):
        return self.email



class OtpToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,         related_name="otps")
    otp_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=secrets.token_hex(3))
    otp_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    otp_expires_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model



class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={"placeholder": "Enter email-address", "class": "form-control"})
)
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={"placeholder": "Enter email-username", "class": "form-control"})
)
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password",widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={"placeholder": "Enter password", "class": "form-control"}
    ),
)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Confirm Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={"placeholder": "Confirm password", "class": "form-control"}
    ),
)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ["email", "username", "password1", "password2"]

signals.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.conf import settings
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import OtpToken
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils import timezone



@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_token(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.is_superuser:
            pass

        else:
            OtpToken.objects.create(
                user=instance,
                otp_expires_at=timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(minutes=5),)
            instance.is_active = False
            instance.save()

        # email credentials
        otp = OtpToken.objects.filter(user=instance).last()

        subject = "Email Verification"
        message = f"""
                            Hi {instance.username}, here is your OTP {otp.otp_code} 
                            it expires in 5 minute, use the url below to redirect back to the website
                            http://127.0.0.1:8000/verify-email/{instance.username}
                            
                            """
        sender = "stefanaikins@gmail.com"
        receiver = [instance.email,]

        # send email
        send_mail(
            subject,
            message,
            sender,
            receiver,
            fail_silently=False,
    )

views.py
def signup(request, *args, **kwargs):

    form = RegisterForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(form)
            messages.success(request, "Account created successfully! An OTP was sent to your Email")
            username = request.POST["username"]
            # return redirect("verify-email", username=request.POST["username"])
            return reverse("verify-email", kwargs={"username": username})
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "signup.html", context)





def verify_email(request, username):
    user = get_user_model().objects.get(username=username)
    user_otp = OtpToken.objects.filter(user=user).last()

    if request.method == "POST":
        # valid token
        if user_otp.otp_code == request.POST["otp_code"]:

            # checking for expired token
            if user_otp.otp_expires_at > timezone.now():
                user.is_active = True
                user.save()
                messages.success(request, "Account activated successfully!! You can Login.")
                return redirect("signin")

            # expired token
            else:
                messages.warning(request, "The OTP has expired, get a new OTP!")
                return redirect("verify-email", username=user.username)

        # invalid otp code
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "Invalid OTP entered, enter a valid OTP!")
            return redirect("verify-email", username=user.username)

    context = {}
    return render(request, "verify_token.html", context)


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
